# Instead of displaying report from SSRS server in PDF, the browser is displaying the raw response from the web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, webclient, ssrs-2012

Here's the code I'm using to display report from a SSRS server in PDF format.

```
var reportServerUrl = new Uri(string.Format("{0}?{1}{2}&rs:aCommand=Render&rs:Format=pdf", 
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ReportServerURL"), 
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ReportFolder"), ItemPath));

var wcli = new WebClient();
wcli.Credentials = CustomReportCredentials.WebClientCredentials;
var fileBuffer = wcli.DownloadData(reportServerUrl);

if (fileBuffer != null)
{
   Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
   Response.AddHeader("content-length", fileBuffer.Length.ToString());
   Response.BinaryWrite(fileBuffer);
}
```

It's works most of the time. However, sometimes when I click a link, instead of getting a report in PDF format, I'm getting some strange results, depending of the browser. In CHROME, I'm getting the source code of the page. In IE, I'm getting the raw response + some stange characters (see image). Then the page times out.

[image]

Honestly, I don't have a clue why this is happening.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: That's usually caused by a doctype setting on the server, where the server doesn't know what kind of data it's sending out, so it assumes text.  You don't say what web server you're using, so I can't suggest a specific fix.

Comment: I'm using the Internet Information Services 8. The side question would be, why the problem is happening only every other time, i.e. I click the link, it displays the report in PDF. The next time, I get the error. The next time, it displays the report perfectly, then I get the error. I'm lost.

Comment: You doing this on a button click?  i would create a handler and then use a hyperlink to download the file.  probably would set attachment on Content-Disposition plus a filename, report.pdf or some such.

Comment: @MikeMiller: `Content-Disposition` is a nice touch and a great tool for handling disobedient clients who absolutely refuse to "force" a download or inline display. But I think this is not the issue here. Still worth a +1 :)

Comment: I think he needs to use get response and write one stream into t'other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see there is a raw binary HTTP response including headers and payload (that is what's making up those weird chracters) interpreted as HTML. I think what you are missing here is a call to [`Response.Clear()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) after setting your headers up:

```
if (fileBuffer != null)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-length", fileBuffer.Length.ToString());
    Response.Clear();
    Response.BinaryWrite(fileBuffer);
}
```

Failing to do so will leave the webserver's default headers in place.

Having said that, I think you do not really need to set the content length of your payload. See the example for [`Response.Flush()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.flush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Can u please write here the way the code should be? At least the fixes that needed to be applied?

Comment: @Richard77: Sorry, I thought it were obvious. I've updated my answer.

Comment: No, it was not obvious for me. For instance, I removed the line adding the header as you advised. Also I added the Response.Flush(). Now things are working fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Richard77: I'll take that as a hint to include examples more often in my answers. But above all I'm glad it's working for you now :)